# Major version should be v0 or v1, not v11

Tags: go

I am trying to include this package in my project: https://github.com/0xProject/0x-mesh/tags

Here the versions are clearly specified as v11.2.0, v11.1.0 and so on.

However when I am trying to `go get` it, I get this error:

```
bash$ go get github.com/0xProject/0x-mesh@v11.2.0
go get: github.com/0xProject/0x-mesh@v11.2.0: invalid version: module contains a go.mod file, so major version must be compatible: should be v0 or v1, not v11
```

Why is this happening? There are tags with 11.2.0 and Releases too. So, why not?
The maximum version I can get with `go get` is v7.1.0-beta+incompatible, it works fine, but above v7 I can't, why is that? Also, is there a clear list on Github that would indicate which versions can be `go get`-ted and which can't?

Comment: See the [documentation on modules](https://go.dev/blog/v2-go-modules), specifically the directory structure including the [major version suffix](https://go.dev/ref/mod#vcs-dir)

Comment: From the README: "This repository is no longer being maintained." And this seems to be true.

Comment: The package version in pkg appears to be Version: v1.0.7 .Check it out : https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/0xProject/0x-mesh

Comment: @ban ohh, I see. So go mod doesn't look in the repo of the original project (github.com/0xProject/0x-mesh), it connects to go.dev website and gets the list of available versions from there?

Comment: Yes, it's connects to go.dev

Comment: @ban, ok, so this is the answer to my question. I thought it was `go get`ting from the original repo. If you post your answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When including packages to the project, it is based on the version at pkg.go.dev. The package version Version: v1.0.7. Check it out:

> pkg.go.dev/github.com/0xProject/0x-mesh